# How to add a local aar dependency into a bintray published library?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, pom.xml, bintray

I have created a library that I share with the world through JFrog Bintray.
I now added a local .aar dependency to my module that I would like to be part of the uploaded package and I don't know how to do it.
I added the local aar via `implementation project(path: ':myLocalDependency-1.3.1')` but I also need it in the pom I create via a script for the bintray I guess, and have no clue how to do it. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Kezong:

```
apply plugin: 'com.kezong.fat-aar'
```

I will create a fat arr containing all the dependencies you want.
In your gradle.build file you and the dependency to your local aar like this:

```
embed project(path: ':myLocalARR-1.3.1-release')
```

Using ***embed*** will ensure that your final arr will contain the java files from your local dependency.

Answer (score 0):

After creating .aar of the module, put that .aar file inside **libs** folder on project/Module project. Make sure you have added below code in build.gradle

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])